# CXF Client + WS-Security + MTOM = Trouble?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, ws-security

I am building a CXF (version 2.7.4) client that calls a WS-Security enabled web service. It uses BinarySecurityToken, encryption and signing. I got CXF working for the "regular" SOAP calls, but when the response comes back as MTOM, I end up getting weird errors in the client:

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:778)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:334)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:96)
...
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Could not find a resolver for URI cid:urn%3Auuid%3AD62B819A5C8E77D41B1391208838268@apache.org and Base null
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Could not find a resolver for URI cid:urn%3Auuid%3AD62B819A5C8E77D41B1391208838268@apache.org and Base null
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipherInput.getDecryptBytes(XMLCipherInput.java:134)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipherInput.getBytes(XMLCipherInput.java:103)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Could not find a resolver for URI cid:urn%3Auuid%3AD62B819A5C8E77D41B1391208838268@apache.org and Base null
    at org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.internalGetInstance(ResourceResolver.java:130)
    at org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.getInstance(ResourceResolver.java:87)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipherInput.getDecryptBytes(XMLCipherInput.java:130)
    ... 51 more
```

I tried calling `setMTOMEnabled(true)` on the binding provider, setting SAAjInInterceptor, AttachmentInInterceptor but still no luck. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I guess another option would be to write a custom ResourceResolver and then somehow provide the attachments through that class. Looks like an overkill...

Comment: What are the rules for XML Security in this sort of situation? I tried reading them once (years ago) but they were very sleep-inducing…

Comment: Ah, I wish I knew. This is a very strange setup. We need to configure custom headers, add binary security token, username token and a timestamp, then sign it all. The response comes back signed and encrypted. CXF handles it fine for most calls, except that one with MTOM attachments...

Answer (score 2):

It all traces back to the fact that CXF doesn't work with MTOM when WSS is enabled :(

[CXF Mailing List One](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Receiving-and-Decrypting-Encrypted-MTOM-Attachments-td5733291.html)

After struggling a bit more with this problem, it looks like one way to resolve that might be including a custom resource resolver and a transformation.

So I added a custom resolver so that WSS know where to find attachment content:

```
package org.integration.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.cxf.message.Attachment;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureInput;
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverContext;
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException;
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverSpi;

public class AttachmentResolverSpi extends ResourceResolverSpi {

    private static final String SUPPORTED_URI_PREFIX = "cid:urn";

    private static final String ATTACHMENT_PREFIX = "cid:";

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AttachmentResolverSpi.class);

    private Collection<Attachment> attachments;

    @Override
    public boolean engineIsThreadSafe() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean engineCanResolveURI(ResourceResolverContext context) {
        if (context.uriToResolve == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return context.uriToResolve.startsWith(SUPPORTED_URI_PREFIX);
    }

    @Override
    public XMLSignatureInput engineResolveURI(ResourceResolverContext context)
            throws ResourceResolverException {
        String resourceId = getResourceId(context);

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Looking up: " + resourceId);
        }

        Attachment attachment = getAttachment(resourceId);

        if (attachment == null) {
            logger.error("Unable to resolve attachment for " + resourceId);

            throw new ResourceResolverException(context.uriToResolve, context.attr, context.baseUri);
        }

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Found attachment: " + attachment);
        }

        XMLSignatureInput result;
        try {
            result = new XMLSignatureInput(attachment.getDataHandler().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to create xml signature input", e);

            throw new ResourceResolverException(context.uriToResolve, context.attr, context.baseUri);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String getResourceId(ResourceResolverContext context) {
        String resourceId = context.uriToResolve;
        try {
            resourceId = URLDecoder.decode(resourceId, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to decode", e1);
        }
        if (resourceId.startsWith(ATTACHMENT_PREFIX)) {
            resourceId = resourceId.substring(ATTACHMENT_PREFIX.length());
        }
        return resourceId;
    }

    private Attachment getAttachment(String resourceId) {
        Collection<Attachment> attachments = getAttachments();
        if (attachments == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for(Attachment a : attachments) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Comparing " + a.getId() + " with " + resourceId);
            }

            if (a.getId().equals(resourceId)) {
                return a;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected Collection<Attachment> getAttachments() {
        if (attachments == null) {
            attachments = AttachmentCachingSaajInInterceptor.getAttachments();
        }
        return attachments;
    }

}
```

Now, additional tweak is to tell CXF how to get the signature value for this content:

```
package org.integration.client;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException;
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.InvalidCanonicalizerException;
import org.apache.xml.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException;
import org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureInput;
import org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform;
import org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformSpi;
import org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformationException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TransformAttachmentCiphertext extends TransformSpi {

    public static final String TRANSFORM_ATTACHMENT_CIPHERTEXT = 
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-SwAProfile-1.1#Attachment-Ciphertext-Transform";

    /**
     * @see org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformSpi#engineGetURI()
     */
    @Override
    public String engineGetURI() {
        return TRANSFORM_ATTACHMENT_CIPHERTEXT;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformSpi#enginePerformTransform(org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureInput,
     *      java.io.OutputStream, org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform)
     */
    @Override
    protected XMLSignatureInput enginePerformTransform(XMLSignatureInput input,
            OutputStream os, Transform transformObject) throws IOException,
            CanonicalizationException, InvalidCanonicalizerException,
            TransformationException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        if (input.isOctetStream() || input.isNodeSet()) {
            if (os == null) {
                byte[] contentBytes = input.getBytes();
                XMLSignatureInput output = new XMLSignatureInput(contentBytes);
                return output;
            }

            if (input.isByteArray() || input.isNodeSet()) {
                os.write(input.getBytes());
            } else {
                try {
                    org.apache.xml.security.utils.Base64.decode(new BufferedInputStream(input.getOctetStreamReal()), os);
                } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to decode real octet stream", e);
                }
            }

            XMLSignatureInput output = new XMLSignatureInput(new byte[] {});
            output.setOutputStream(os);
            return output;
        }
        return input;
    }

}
```

Finally, those two elements need to be registered with CXF:

```
import org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver;
...
ResourceResolver.register(AttachmentResolverSpi.class, true);
org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.register(TransformAttachmentCiphertext.TRANSFORM_ATTACHMENT_CIPHERTEXT, TransformAttachmentCiphertext.class);
```

Please don't ask me how, but CXF starts decrypting SOAP messages with Attachments after these manipulations. But that's not a complete solution as it still doesn't work with MTOM attachments... What happens is that CXF attempts to update the DOM model with the attachment content. This approach doesn't work for two reasons. First the binary attachments are don't usually make well-formed XML elements. Second, the Attachment instances on the SOAP message are not updated. To fix that, and finally produce a working solution, I had to hack DocumentSerializer (resolves problem 1 by base64 encoding the content if it can't be parsed) and XMLCipher (resolves problem 2 by replacing the Attachment instances).